# Detect user switched to fullscreen

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, fullscreenchange

When my web page is requesting a full screen access using `requestFullscreen` from [Fullscreen API](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/), it can install a `fullscreenchange` event handler to be notified of going in / out of fullscreen. However this handler does not seem to be notified when user goes to fullscreen on his own (like pressing F11 in Chrome).

Is there a way how to be notified of this? My motivation is I would like to lock a pointer using [Pointer Lock API](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-pointerlock-20161027/) once user presses F11 or uses the browser menu to switch to fullscreen.

Comment: Maybe you could register a window resize handler and check if the window size is the same as the screen size

Comment: You could register an event handler when the user presses F11

Comment: @JonathanNewton - like this :) `window.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) { if (evt.key === 'F11') { /* fullscreen */ } });`

Comment: F11 can easily change, or user can enter fullscreen from a menu, not by keyboard. Is there some cleaner and more general way?

Comment: @Ysragh yeah exactly! I'm not sure what the edge cases are but it seems like a winner

Comment: @Ysragh While related, I do not think it is a duplicate. I would prefer to be notified, not to check. Still it is helpful, as if there is no such event, I can do a regular check on each frame and handle the change myself.

Comment: @Suma why not register the event then send it to a controller/message bus